# Откуда берутся значения current & history?

Tags: javascript

Приветствую) Подскажите пожалуйста, откуда берутся значения current & history?

[image: text]

Answer (score 2):

Значение для `current` передается первым параметром в метод `find`, а значение `history` - вторым.

Начиная с вызова `find(1, "1")`.

Answer (score 2):

Им присваивается значение при вызове функции `find` в строке:

```
return find(1, "1");
```